# zend2 forms and action attribute

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

in my EditController I have indexAction :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $delete = new DeleteForm();
    $view = new ViewModel(array('delete' => $delete ));
    return $view;
}
```

and the view

```
<?php
    $formDelete = $this->delete;
    $formDelete->prepare();        
    $formDelete->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL, array('controller'=>'Register', 'action' => 'process')));
?>
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($formDelete);?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?=$this->formLabel($formDelete->get('reason')); ?>        
        <?=$this->formElement($formDelete->get('reason'))?>
        <?=$this->formElementErrors($formDelete->get('reason'))?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?=$this->formElement($formDelete->get('delete-button'))?>
    </div>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag();?>
```

Despite I have action attribute set to RegisterController and processAction in page source I see always the same action. In setAttribute $this->url I can type whatever I want, in the code source always is

```
<form method="post" name="deleteForm" enctype="multipart/formdata" action="/App/public/element/edit" id="deleteForm">
```

Comment: You have two return statements in your controller's action?

Comment: ups, it was copy/paste mistake ... thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the URL helper should be the name of the route you want to use, not `NULL`. By using `NULL`, ZF will fall back on using the current route, which I'd guess is not correct in your case.